# Genetic Algorithm for Snake not converging

Tags: python, machine-learning, genetic-algorithm

I'm trying to train an AI to play snake with a genetic algorithm. I'm using the Python library NEAT for the training. The problem is that the training doesn't converge and the AI doesn't learn. Here's the training code:

```
class SnakeEnv():

def __init__(self, screen):
    self.action_space = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
    self.state = None
    pygame.init()
    self.screen = screen
    self.snakes = [] 
    self.total_reward = 0

def reset(self):
    self.__init__()

    
def get_state(self):
    return np.reshape(self.snake.board, (400, 1)).T / 5

def render(self, snake):
    self.screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    snake.food.render()
    snake.render()
    pygame.display.flip()

def step(self, snake, action):
    snake.move(action)
    self.render(snake)

def close(self):
    pygame.quit()


def eval_genomes(self, genomes, config):
    global nets_g
    nets_g = []
    nets = []
    snakes = []
    global ge_g
    ge_g = []
    ge = []
    for genome_id, genome in genomes:
        genome.fitness = 0
        net = neat.nn.FeedForwardNetwork.create(genome, config)
        nets.append(net)
        snakes.append(Snake(self.screen))
        ge.append(genome)
    
    ge_g = ge.copy()
    nets_g = nets.copy()
    run = True
    #Main loop
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
                break

        for x, snake in enumerate(snakes):
            if(snake.done):
                continue
            ge[x].fitness += 0.1

            """
            Inputs to the neural net:
            Vertical distance from food to head
            Horizontal distance from food to head
            Vertical distance to nearest wall from head
            Horizontal distance to nearest wall from head
            Distance from head to body segment (default -1)
            """

            snake_x = snake.head.x
            snake_y = snake.head.y
            food_x = snake.food.x 
            food_y = snake.food.y 

            food_vert = snake_y - food_y
            food_horz = snake_x - food_x
            wall_vert = min(snake_y, 600 - snake_y)
            wall_horz = min(snake_x, 600 - snake_x)
            body_front = snake.body_front()
            output = np.argmax(nets[snakes.index(snake)].activate((food_vert, food_horz, wall_vert, wall_horz, body_front)))
            state = snake.move(output)
            if state["Food"] == True:
                ge[snakes.index(snake)].fitness += 1

            if state["Died"] == True:
                ge[snakes.index(snake)].fitness -= 1
                #nets.pop(snakes.index(snake))
                #ge.pop(snakes.index(snake))
                #snakes.pop(snakes.index(snake))
            all_done = [snake.done for snake in snakes]
            if(False not in all_done):
                run = False


def run(self, config_file):
    config = neat.config.Config(neat.DefaultGenome, neat.DefaultReproduction, neat.DefaultSpeciesSet, neat.DefaultStagnation, config_file)
    population = neat.Population(config)
    population.add_reporter(neat.StdOutReporter(True))
    stats = neat.StatisticsReporter()
    population.add_reporter(stats)
    best = population.run(self.eval_genomes, 200)
    print('\nBest genome:\n{!s}'.format(best))
    best_net = nets_g[ge_g.index(best)]
    pickle.dump(best_net, open('best.pkl', 'wb'))
```

(Pretend like my code is indented, the editor isn't working for some reason)
Here's the `conf.txt` file:

```
[NEAT]
fitness_criterion     = max
fitness_threshold     = 20
pop_size              = 50
reset_on_extinction   = False

[DefaultGenome]
# node activation options
activation_default      = relu
activation_mutate_rate  = 0.0
activation_options      = relu

# node aggregation options
aggregation_default     = sum
aggregation_mutate_rate = 0.0
aggregation_options     = sum

# node bias options
bias_init_mean          = 0.0
bias_init_stdev         = 1.0
bias_max_value          = 10.0
bias_min_value          = -10.0
bias_mutate_power       = 0.5
bias_mutate_rate        = 0.9
bias_replace_rate       = 0.1

# genome compatibility options
compatibility_disjoint_coefficient = 1.0
compatibility_weight_coefficient   = 0.5

# connection add/remove rates
conn_add_prob           = 0.7
conn_delete_prob        = 0.7

# connection enable options
enabled_default         = True
enabled_mutate_rate     = 0.01

feed_forward            = True
initial_connection      = full

# node add/remove rates
node_add_prob           = 0.7
node_delete_prob        = 0.7

# network parameters
num_hidden              = 0
num_inputs              = 5
num_outputs             = 4

# node response options
response_init_mean      = 1.0
response_init_stdev     = 0.0
response_max_value      = 30.0
response_min_value      = -30.0
response_mutate_power   = 0.0
response_mutate_rate    = 0.0
response_replace_rate   = 0.0

# connection weight options
weight_init_mean        = 0.0
weight_init_stdev       = 1.0
weight_max_value        = 30
weight_min_value        = -30
weight_mutate_power     = 0.5
weight_mutate_rate      = 0.8
weight_replace_rate     = 0.1

[DefaultSpeciesSet]
compatibility_threshold = 3.0

[DefaultStagnation]
species_fitness_func = max
max_stagnation       = 20
species_elitism      = 2

[DefaultReproduction]
elitism            = 2
survival_threshold = 0.2
```

As you can see I train for 200 generations. The results are pretty odd. The snake consistently gets a single piece of food but then immediately runs into a wall. It's sort of learning but not fully. I've tried to let it train for more generations, but there's no difference. I think the problem may be with my inputs to the neural nets, but I'm not sure.

EDIT: I changed the network architecture so that it now has 4 output nodes with a `relu` activation. The problem is now that the code freezes on the step where the output is computed (`output = np.argmax(nets[snakes.index(snake)].activate((food_vert, food_horz, wall_vert, wall_horz, body_front)))`)

Answer (score 2):

From glancing over your code, you seem to have some bug(s):

```
for x, snake in enumerate(snakes):
    ge[x].fitness += 0.1
```

Within the `for` loop you are `pop()`ing elements from both the `snakes` and the `ge` lists. In Python you should never change a list while iterating over it. Later in the loop you are using `snakes.index(snake)` insted of `x` to index the same list. Because of this, the reward for staying alive will probably go to the wrong snakes.

You could copy the list before iterating, but repeating `snakes.index(snake)` everywhere also is an anti-pattern. You need to find a different solution. For example you could use a `snake.dead` flag.

### Output Shape

You seem to be scaling the output of a single neuron into integer range. This makes the task a bit difficult (but not impossible) to solve for the NN, because close-together numbers don't actually map to similar actions.

The more common approach would be to use a separate neuron for each output, and select the action with highest activation. (Or to use softmax to select an action with random probabilities. This adds noise but makes the fitness landscape much smoother, because then even small changes to the weights will have some effect on fitness.)

### General Advice

You cannot expect to write bug-free code. When your code is part of an optimization loop debugging is extra-tricky because the optimization changes the effect of bugs.

Run your code in a simpler setting first. For example, you could ignore the output of the neural net and always do the same action (or random actions) instead. Think about  what is supposed to happen. Maybe track some snakes and their reward manually step-by-step, e.g. with print statements.

The point is: reduce the number of things you are debugging at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I changed it so that the neural net now has 4 output nodes, with a `relu` activation. However, the training now freezes after a few generations. It nearly always freezes at the line where the neural network is computing the output.

Comment: Additionally, I have to remove snakes from the list - doesn't NEAT work until the population size is 0?

Comment: NEAT has a constant population per generation (you have configured it to 50). The list you're removing from is a local variable in `eval_genomes()`, so it's just used during fitness evaluation and cannot be accessed after that.

Comment: Well, some of your lists are `global`, but still they are not owned by or passed back to NEAT-python, they are only `global` to print the final value.

Comment: Just changed the code so that now snakes aren't popped from the list but rather just skipped over when they're done, which I keep track of with the `snake.done` flag. However, the code still freezes, usually at the step where the network computes the output.